# Are global symmetries of smooth functionals local?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, symmetry

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$

Let $\M,\N$ be smooth manifolds, $\M$ oriented and equipped with a Riemannian metric.

Let $L : J^1(\M,\N) \to \mathbb R$ be smooth; We define a functional $E_{\M,\N}:C^{\infty}(\M,\N) \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

Given a $C^{\infty}$ map $u : \M \to \N$,
we define its prolongation $j^1u : \M \to J^1(\M,\N)$ by $$j^1u(x) = (x, u(x), Du(x)),$$ and define $E$ by the formula

$$ E_{\M,\N}(u)=\int_{\M} L\big(j^1u)\text{Vol}_{\M}.$$

($\text{Vol}_{\M}$ is the Riemannian volume form of $\M$).

**Definition:** We say $f \in \text{Diff}(\M)$ is a (source) symmetry of $E_{\M,\N}$, if 
$$ E_{\M,\N}(u)=E_{\M,\N}(u \circ f) \, \text{ for every } \,u \in C^{\infty}(\M,\N)$$

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ is a local source symmetry? i.e does the equality

$$ E_{f(U),\N}(u)=E_{U,\N}(u \circ f) \, \text{ for every } \,u \in C^{\infty}(f(U),\N)$$

hold for every open subset $U \subseteq \M$?

($U,f(U)$ are subsets of $\M$ so $E_{U,\N},E_{f(U),\N}$ are defined by restricting the domain of integration).

Equivalently, is $f$ a "pointwise-symmetry"-  does $$ \big(L(u) \circ f \big)\cdot f^*\text{Vol}_{\M}=L(u \circ f)\cdot \text{Vol}_{\M} \, \,?$$

**Edit:**

The answer is clearly no without any more restrictions on $L$;

If we take $L\equiv1$, we get $E_{U,\N}(u)=\text{Vol}(U)$ for every $u \in C^{\infty}(f(U),\N)$. This implies any diffeomorphism $f:\M \to \M$ is a source symmetry, but it will be a *local* symmetry only if $\text{Vol}(U)=\text{Vol}(f(U))$ for every $U \subseteq \M$, i.e only $f$ is volume-preserving.

> So, we should assume $L$ is nowhere locally constant (w.r.t the standard topology on the jet space). Is this enough?